# How to detect if an element is a form element

Tags: javascript, forms

In my code, I am trying to detected if the last clicked on element is a `form` element where setting its `name` attribute would be appropriate.

What I've written works:

```
    const tag = lastElement.tagName;
    if (tag === "INPUT" || tag === "TEXTAREA" || tag === "SELECT") {
      ...
    }
```

But I am wondering if there is a more robust/elegant way to do this, like

```
    if (lastElement instanceof FormFieldElement) {
      ...
    }
```

Is there such a common class?

Comment: `if(["INPUT","TEXTAREA","SELECT"].includes(tag))` ?

Comment: To clarify, by "form element", are you saying that you want to know if the element is a child of a `form` tag?  If so, why not just check for that...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a form element"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and researched this myself. According to Mozilla MDN, there's no common element after HTMLElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

(Select also doesn't share class hierarchy)